# UNIX Why are my array values not returning correctly? UNIX

Tags: unix, scripting, vi

I want to write a script such that when I call
    ls -lp | insertScriptNameHere

it stores the text sent to it int an array,

this is what I have in VI so far

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i int =0

while read line; do    

array1[$int]="$line"

done

for ((int=0; int<=${#array1[x]}; int++));

do

echo $array1[$int]
done
```

this is producing a very strange output, it is copying the final line sent to it 61 times, I am new to unix and unix syntax, so please do not get mad if I am missing something very basic, I feel as though my logic is correct, i feel im messing up my syntax

Answer (score 0):

On the last part it seems you didn't reinitialize your integer to 0 that could be throwing you off